# Cassandra Timestamp+Counter

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am currently stumped on how to model something in Cassandra.

What I *want* is this:

```
create table counts(
    user varchar,
    last_event timestamp,
    event_count counter,
    primary key ((user))
);
```

The goal here is to store those two pieces of data (event_count and last_event) in a way that can be efficiently retrieved given a user.

Additionally, there may be multiple threads writing this data at the same time, so the counter type, which handles that case nicely, is quite useful.

However, I know that it is impossible to combine a counter and a timestamp in the same table.  Is there some other, alternative way to model this data that could work?

I realize I can store all of the events as their own rows, but we need to be able to quickly and efficiently retrieve the last_event and event_count for a given user.

EDIT for clarity:  I have a stream of timestamps associated with users. I wish to store the total count of timestamps and the most recent timestamp for each user, and I'd like to optimize for a fast lookup for a specific user.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your primary key `(user,timestamp)`. This will make a separate partition for each user and each counter in the partition will be ordered by the timestamp of last event.

```
create table counts(    
    user varchar,     
    last_event timestamp,     
    event_count counter,     
    primary key (user, last_event) );
```

Your partitions will look like

```
[username -> [time1, counter] , [time2, counter] .... ]
```

Edit:

There are several solutions to the updated question.  I think the easiest way to do this is with two tables.

```
create table lastEvent (
   user varchar,
   event timeuuid, // Time uuid to avoid collosions
   event_data, // Anything else you want to retreive with the last event
   PRIMARY KEY (user,event)
)
```

This table is responsible for tracking the events in a time ordered fashion. Selecting from this table while ordering by descending time stamp will let us retrieve the most recent events. We keep this separate from the state information which we keep in the next table

```
create table eventsPerUser (
   user varchar,
   eventcount counter,
   PRIMARY KE (user)
)
```

This event is simply a lookup between users and how many events have occurred for said user.

You would update both of these tables at the same time in your application.

Comment: How would I keep that data up to date though?

Say a new event comes in, (it's essentially just a timestamp), how do I update the data?  I have to insert a new row, since it has a different timestamp, so how do I keep the counter accurate?

Comment: Your comment seems to be asking a different question than your initial question. Perhaps you can give a full example of the workflow that is actually occurring. I'm not sure you want counters at all if the model I showed you doesn't make sense.

Comment: Essentially, I have a continual stream of timestamps associated with users. I wish to store the count of timestamps and the most recent timestamp for each user.